# Umbraco on Azure: Template not found and System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: azure, umbraco

I am fairly new to Umbraco(v7).

I have installed Umbraco from Nuget in Visual Studio(sample website), its working fine in local. However, when I deploy it in Azure(App Service) I got multiple instances of two types of errors in the log file.

**Error Type 1:**

> System.Exception: No physical template file was found for template
>   Home

Also,

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find the view
>   ~/Views/MacroPartials/latestBlogposts.cshtml, the following locations
>   were searched: ~/Views/MacroPartials/latestBlogposts.cshtml

and lot more...

**Error Type 2:**

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

To fix *Error 1* I included all the cshtml in the Views folder to the project. Now I can see them on server, but the error persists.

For *Error 2* I added the TLS1.2 setting, as suggested [here](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/74628-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send). Although I doubt it has anything related to my case, I still did it. And of course, it didn't fixed the error.

Comment: Have you verified that the views and partials are present on the file system? The files being registered in the .csproj doesn't necessarily mean that they are on the file system.

Comment: @bowserm yes I verified it using Kudu

Comment: Do you see errors on the front end? Or are do these errors only appear in the logs? Can you navigate to the Settings section in the Umbraco backoffice and click on each template? Under the template name, Umbraco should list the path to the template file. Did you do this as you verified the files on the file system via Kudu?

Comment: Has the location of the Views folder changed from the Root directory? Also do you have any examples of where you are calling your partials from (i.e. @Html.Partials("\Views\Partials\Test") etc.)? Just wondering if you might have misspelled a path etc.

Comment: @bowserm Front end do not load at all, it says "Server error" I verified the path its correct.

Comment: @CraigMayers No I didn't changed anything. I am using the default Starter Kit and deployed it as is.

Comment: @GauravMathur Something has gone a miss somewhere along the lines... Does it work on your local machine? If not, I would suggest setting up a new instance and going through the motions again. In regards to error 2 - You will see my suggestion is the correct fix on the Umbraco forum. This usually occurs when your site is trying to talk to a API but using the older out of date TLS protocols. If your site is talking to any API's then am not sure why you are seeing this error here.

Comment: Also, can verfiy if you have set the necessary folder permissions on the server? See the following guide for assistance: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/permissions

Comment: @CraigMayers yes it is working fine on my local machine. No issues at all.